# LINQ query fails with nullable variable ormlite

Tags: linq, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm trying to write following LINQ query using ServiceStack Ormlite.

```
dbConn.Select<Product>(p => p.IsActive.HasValue && p.IsActive.Value)
```

Here, Product is my item class and "IsActive" is Nullable Bool property in that class. When this line executes it always throws "InvalidOperationException" with the message

***variable 'p' of type '' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined***

I tried different variants as following but still same exception result

```
dbConn.Select<Product>(p => p.IsActive.HasValue == true && p.IsActive.Value == true)
dbConn.Select<Product>(p => p.IsActive != null && p.IsActive.Value == true)
```

But if I just write

```
dbConn.Select<Product>(p => p.IsActive.HasValue)
```

then it works.

I'm puzzled what is the problem? Is this servicestack ormlite issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nature of the Linq. In order to achieve what you need, you will need to use two where closes:

```
 dbConn.Where<Product>(p => p.IsActive.HasValue).Where(p=>p.Value==true);
```

Comment: Thanks @Yuri. Seems like time to shake up my LINQ knowledge :)

Comment: Yes, first Where produces result which includes both false and true values

Answer (score 2):

My answer can handle Nullable value like "value" and "HasValue" with servicestack ormlite. And But also with datetime nullable ,like 'createdate.value.Year'. 
you must change *two* place.

1. **modify VisitMemberAccess method:**

```html
protected virtual object VisitMemberAccess(MemberExpression m)
        {
            if (m.Expression != null)
            {
                 if (m.Member.DeclaringType.IsNullableType())
                 {
                    if (m.Member.Name == nameof(Nullable<bool>.Value))
                        return Visit(m.Expression);
                    if (m.Member.Name == nameof(Nullable<bool>.HasValue))
                    {
                        var doesNotEqualNull = Expression.NotEqual(m.Expression, Expression.Constant(null));
                            return Visit(doesNotEqualNull); // Nullable<T>.HasValue is equivalent to "!= null"
                    }
                    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Expression '{0}' accesses unsupported property '{1}' of Nullable<T>", m, m.Member));
                }
                if (m.Member.DeclaringType == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    var ExpressionInfo = m.Expression as MemberExpression;
                    if (ExpressionInfo.Member.DeclaringType.IsNullableType())
                    {
                        if (ExpressionInfo.Member.Name == nameof(Nullable<bool>.Value))
                        {
                            var modelType = (ExpressionInfo.Expression as MemberExpression).Expression.Type;
                            var tableDef = modelType.GetModelDefinition();
                            var columnName = (ExpressionInfo.Expression as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
                            var QuotedColumnName = GetQuotedColumnName(tableDef, columnName);
                            if (m.Member.Name == "Year")
                            {
                                return new PartialSqlString(string.Format("DATEPART(yyyy,{0})", QuotedColumnName));
                            }
                            if (m.Member.Name == "Month")
                                return new PartialSqlString(string.Format("DATEPART(mm,{0})", QuotedColumnName));
                        }                            
                        if (ExpressionInfo.Member.Name == nameof(Nullable<bool>.HasValue))
                        {
                            var doesNotEqualNull = Expression.NotEqual(ExpressionInfo.Expression, Expression.Constant(null));
                            return Visit(doesNotEqualNull); // Nullable<T>.HasValue is equivalent to "!= null"
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var modelType = ExpressionInfo.Expression.Type;
                        var tableDef = modelType.GetModelDefinition();
                        var columnName = ExpressionInfo.Member.Name;
                        var QuotedColumnName = GetQuotedColumnName(tableDef, columnName);
                        if (m.Member.Name == "Year")
                            return new PartialSqlString(string.Format("DATEPART(yyyy,{0})", QuotedColumnName));
                        if (m.Member.Name == "Month")
                            return new PartialSqlString(string.Format("DATEPART(mm,{0})", QuotedColumnName));
                    }
                }
                if (m.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Parameter || m.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
                { 
                    var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)m.Member;

                    var modelType = m.Expression.Type;
                    if (m.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
                    {
                        var unaryExpr = m.Expression as UnaryExpression;
                        if (unaryExpr != null)
                        {
                            modelType = unaryExpr.Operand.Type;
                        }
                    }

                    var tableDef = modelType.GetModelDefinition();
                    if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsEnum)
                        return new EnumMemberAccess(
                            GetQuotedColumnName(tableDef, m.Member.Name), propertyInfo.PropertyType);

                    return new PartialSqlString(GetQuotedColumnName(tableDef, m.Member.Name));
                }
            }

            var member = Expression.Convert(m, typeof(object));
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(member);
            var getter = lambda.Compile();
            return getter();
        }
```

2. **modify VisitLambda method** :

```html
protected virtual object VisitLambda(LambdaExpression lambda)
        {
            if (lambda.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess && sep == " ")
            {
                MemberExpression m = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;

                if (m.Expression != null)
                {
                    string r = VisitMemberAccess(m).ToString();
                    if (m.Member.DeclaringType.IsNullableType())
                        return r;
                    return string.Format("{0}={1}", r, GetQuotedTrueValue());
                }

            }
            return Visit(lambda.Body);
        }
```